# How to use the same workspace in sublime and force ide

Tags: apex, eclipse, sublime

I want to share the same workspace between sublime text and Force Ide. Rigth now I only use Sublime Text and I cant import the content of this project to Force Ide. I can do that or I need two different workspaces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just did this the other day. This is what I did:
1. Created a new Force.com project in Eclipse
2. I choice the same name and workspace location as the Sublime project
3. When prompted for items to pull down in the metadata I set it to None
4. This step may differ but I used git to revert my changes to the package file so that it would return to what I had in sublime.

Comment: I tried it and was OK but now When I tried to refresh the project in Sublime I get this error Operation:
   Result: [OPERATION FAILED]: Could not find metadata types to refresh

Comment: @lopez.regalado.fj did you revert your package.xml file? I just refreshed my project without any problems.

Comment: How can I revert my package.xml?

Comment: @lopez.regalado.fj do you have backups or use source control? Otherwise, does sublime let you edit the project so you can select everything you want to pull down again?

Comment: Yes, but if i try edit the project and download again i get the same error.

Comment: @lopez.regalado.fj Hmm, not sure what happened there but you could try creating a new project, selecting the metadata you want and then replacing your package file and then deleting the new project. Sounds like something is messed up in it.